# URL recording after the URI in google Analytics All Data view?

Tags: google-analytics

In my Google analytics account, All data view is recording URL after URI. When I click on the page it shows not found. Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have probably set "skillatwill.com" within your View settings, as Default page. This gets appended to all pages, that end with `/` Try to clear this field. Please note, that this will not fix already collected data.